# How do I manually add a remote user to the gdm login screen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, domain, gdm

My company is using a Centrify domain server and I have to use my user there to log into my Ubuntu (18.04) laptop. Currently when I turn on my machine the login screen only displays the name of a sysadmin user that I don't know the password for and I have to click on the text `login as a different user` and then manually type in my username.

I would rather not have to do this. Is there a way I can force gdm to show my username in the login screen so I don't have to type it in after every boot?

Comment: Additional info: My domain user can sudo on the local machine, so I can change any file. I assume I would have to edit one of the files under /etc/gdm3 but all of my google searches have resulted in answers detailing how to remove a user from the list or how to add the "login as a different user" button

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I simply faked the `/etc/passwd` to include my domain user. You can do that by adding the entry yourself at the bottom of the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
echo $USERNAME:x:$(id -u $USERNAME):$(id -g $USERNAME)::/home/$USERNAME:/bin/bash | sudo tee -a /etc/passwd
```

In my company we use centrify and I have the command line `adquery` which makes it even easier:

```
adquery user $USERNAME | sudo tee -a /etc/passwd
```

Reboot and you should be good to go.

I had also edited the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and added a `[greeter]` section:

```
[greeter]
Include=<your_username>
```

then reconfigure GDM:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

But I am not sure it is required. That alone didn't allow to show my username in the login list.